# HTML anchor stays after PHP reload with header location, why?

Tags: php, html, header, location, anchor

I have a signup page with a signup form. The action of this form is

```
<?=$php_self?>#signup
```

When form is sent the actual form validation and signup are processed and if there were errors you'll just stay on the signup page. that's why the anchor is used, it will make sure the signup form stays in focus even on smaller screens (there is a login form above the signup form).

If the signup is successful a header reload will occur

```
if($input->call('signup')) header('Location: '.$php_self.'?pID=1');
```

That will load the "firstlogin" page.

Everything works it's just that after the reload using header location the signup anchor stays. This is not a huge problem, it's just that it's not my intention and I want to understand why (and if I can prevent it). The url after header reload:

/.../index.php?pID=1#signup

Why does the anchor stay after the new page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
}
```

Comment: Not working, but that might be due to my lacking javascript skills (it IS javascript, right?) :P